# How to find current date of computer in ROS?

Tags: c++, linux, ros

I'm trying to calculate difference of dates based on the current computer date, in ROS. Which function can I use to do that? Or atleast get the current date of computer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a better site to post your question. http://answers.ros.org/questions/

Answer (score 2):

You should try Google next time, but here:

```
ros::Time::now();
ros::Duration difference = ros::Time::now() - previous_time;
```

http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Time

EDIT:
To get a text string, you have to convert it: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/2030

```
boost::posix_time thistime = from_time_t(difference);
```

Once you have it converted to [boost::posix_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/date_time/doc/class_ptime.html#conversiontostring), you can:

```
std::string to_simple_string(thistime);
```

Which will spit it out like: "2002-Jan-01 10:00:01.123456789"
You can also see what thistime.date(); gives you, it looks like it might be simpler: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/date_time/doc/class_date.html

Comment: I need the the date as in dd:mm:yyyy, not just time.